# Django 1.7 tests against production DB rather than create test DB

Tags: django, database, django-testing, django-tests

I've been handed a django-1.7 installation and asked to make testing work for an in-house django module. (specifically, we're running `Django==1.7.9` and `psycopg2==2.5.4`)

After two days of head scratching, I'm still finding that when I run `manage.py test mymodule`, it's testing against the **production** postgres database rather than creating a test database into which to install my fixture data.

Weirdly, I don't get any error messages or any indicators that it's trying to create a test database at all. The testsuite simply tests against the production database.

I've verified that the user I'm running as has CREATE/DROP privileges in postgres for a test database.

I've also tried to get my testsuite to use an in-memory database by specifying a `TEST` database engine as the built-in sqlite3, per the docs, like so:

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'NAME': DATABASE_NAME,
    'PASSWORD': 'nottherealpassword',
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'USER': 'nottherealdbuser',
    'PORT': '5432',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'TEST': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'
            }
    },
  }
```

No change in behavior with this configuration, either, and no indication that it's even **trying** to create one. Is there some scenario in which the test runner declines to even attempt to create a test database for a given module? I've tried both the default django runner as well as `django_nose` with no change in behavior.

My preferred outcome will be to test against a tiny in-memory database that I'd populate with fixtures; my second preferred outcome would be to create a test database in postgres but **without** having to run every migration from the beginning of time.

Comment: What kind of tests are you running? Unit tests? Are you specifically using LiveServerTestCase in your tests so it tests against a junk db? Can  you post a sample of one of your tests?

Comment: I'm attempting unit tests, yes. LiveServerTestCase came in sometime after 1.7, so that's not available ... and the regular `django.test.TestCase` allegedly handles test database creation, so I'd be surprised if I needed to use a different case.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that we were/are using a multidb setup. Setting `DATABASE_ROUTERS` to a blank iterable `[]` re-enabled testing database creation.